# android: gradle: same version for dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I want to add fcm to my android project. Following the guide, I added firebase to my app and inserted the dependency. But now I get the error

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

on the appcompat dependency(or maybe I just haven't noticed it before)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myApp.ginso.com.azul"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Can anyone tell me, what I have to change?

Comment: exclude *support group* from **espresso-core** dependencies.

Comment: The rest of the message should tell which support library has the issue, you should just add it to the dependencies with the latest release.

Comment: edited my question to include the full message

Comment: no, still no change

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that **espresso-core** is using older dependency of *support library group*. Increase it to latest version (3.0.2 or whatever latest is) or use below code instead of your existing code to explicitly remove *support group* from it:

```
androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Is there any other external dependencies?

Comment: what du mean by external? I only added firebase with the assistant and inserted the firebase-messaging dependency

Comment: What about excluding it from **firebase messaging** dependency too?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your libraries have used an older version of dependencies.

To resolve this add this dependency and try again

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Try to remove build folder first and then clean build.